# Cargar una variabale List<string> con una función

Tags: c#

Os cuento, tengo una función que hace llamada a través de una query a la base de datos que se lanza cuándo el usuario ha escrito dos caracteres en un campo y así, quiero filtrar la lista. (igual que una función de jQuery con Ajax en web). Os pongo el código de la función a la que llama el código:

```
public static List<string> listadoViajes(string prefixText)
        {
            //SqlConnection constr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT (CAST((LTRIM(RTRIM(Nombre)) + ' ' + (LTRIM(RTRIM(Apellidos)) AS VARCHAR(150))) Nombre
                                                    FROM tbl_UsuarioAgencia
                                                    WHERE idAgencia = 1 AND
                                                     AND (Nombre LIKE '%'+@param+'%' OR Apellidos LIKE '%'+@param+'%' OR usr LIKE '%'+@param+'%')"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", prefixText);

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    List<string> Listado = new List<string>();
                    //SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlDataReader();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    //sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
                    while (sdr.Read())
                        Listado.Add(sdr["Nombre"].ToString());
                    con.Close();
                    return Listado;
                }
            }
        }
```

Ahora os pongo el código desde el que se hace llamada a esta función:

```
private void TxtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cadena = TxtBuscar.Text;
            if(cadena.Length > 2)
            {
                clases.UsuarioAgencia objComUsuario = new clases.UsuarioAgencia();
                List<string> listaUsuarios = new List<string>();
                listaUsuarios = objComUsuario.listadoViajes(cadena);
            }
        }
```

Ahora os comento, en la línea "listaUsuarios = objComUsuario.listadoViajes(cadena);" me da error y no me deja asignarle el valor de la función, y eso que también devuelve un List

¿Cuál es el fallo? Seguro que es super simple, pero a mi no me sale.

Gracias

Comment: Y que error te da??

Comment: Ya lo he arreglado. Le he quitado el comando static y ya está funcionando. Gracias